# What is the difference in the two forms of “being able”?

Tags: sens, choix-de-mot

I would like to know the difference in meaning between:

> J'arrive à

and

> Je peux

Comment: The third and probably most common form is “je sais [le faire]”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an every language:

> J'arrive à grimper sur un arbre.

It's a proven action. I can because I tried before.

> Je peux grimper sur un arbre.

I can if someone asks me.

I think the first sentence is more likely to have a successful action.

Comment: Yep that's exactly what I had in mind. Cheers!

Comment: English explanation is unclear.  Please edit for clarification.  L'explication en Anglais n'est pas claire.  Veuillez mettre à jour pour clarifier.

Answer (score 6):

*Arriver à* expresses an achievement. It is closer to *manage to [do sth.]* in English. It is almost synonymous with *réussir à*. *Arriver à* is slightly informal and more often used in speech whereas *réussir à* or *parvenir à* is more often used in writing.

> Je n'arrive pas à atteindre l'étagère du haut. Je vais chercher un tabouret. *(I can't reach the top shelf. I'll go and get a stool.)*
>   Je suis arrivé à faire cet exercice. *(I managed to solve this exercise.)*
>   Je n'arrive pas toujours à le comprendre. *(I don't always understand him.)*

*Arriver à* is about achieving a specific action. To express an ability, you can use *être capable de*. More generally, *pouvoir* expresses ability or willingness.

> Je ne peux pas atteindre l'étagère du haut, je suis trop petit. *(I can't reach the top shelf. I'm too short.)*
>   Je ne peux pas faire cet exercice, je n'ai pas encore suivi la leçon correspondante. *(I can't solve this exercise, I haven't done the corresponding lesson yet.)*
>   Je serais capable de le faire, mais je n'en ai pas envie. *(I would be capable of doing it, but I don't feel like it.)*
>   Si tu as besoin d'un coup de main, je peux t'aider. *(If you need a hand, I can help you.)*

Answer (score 1):

*J'arrive à grimper ...* indique une progression dans la capacité : j'ai essayé, j'y suis arrivé, mais j'ai des difficultés à le faire.

*Je peux grimper ...* est une affirmation de la capacité : *je suis capable de*.

Comment: The basic definition of the two words is okay. I mean the differences in nuances between the two when «arriver» is used in the sense of «being able to». Eg.J'arrive fermer la porte.

Comment: About edit : J'arrive à grimper sans difficulté... J'utilise j'arrive pourtant....

Comment: @Jahnux73 Il y a inversion du sens avec le *sans* : s'il n'y a pas de difficulté, c'est que vous le *pouvez*. La 'traduction' inverse de *j'arrive pourtant* se rapprocherait plutôt de *malgré les difficultés j'arrive à*, ce qui éloigne de "grimper sans difficulté".

Comment: @cl-r Usain Bolt arrive à courir le 100m en moins de 30 secondes. Je reste dubitatif sur la difficulté, cela dépend du contexte. Il faudrait que d'autres personnes tranchent.

Comment: @Jahnux73 J'y arrive encore en moins de 30 secondes, mais pas en moins de 10 :), en revanche, il a eu des difficultés à surmonter pour y arriver, des entrainements : une performance olympique n'est jamais facile puisque c'est le résultat d'efforts constants.