# Y a-t-il une différence entre « du haut », « le plus haut » et « le dernier » ?

Tags: choix-de-mot, indications-de-lieu

Gilles [a écrit](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/7567/1995) :

> Je n'arrive pas à atteindre l'étagère **du haut**.
>   (I can't reach the top shelf.)

Pourquoi « du haut », au lieu de « le plus haut » ou « le dernier » ? Les phrases suivantes sont-elles correctes :

1. Je n'arrive pas à atteindre l'étagère **la plus haute**.
2. Je n'arrive pas à atteindre **la dernière** étagère.

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

« L'étagère la plus haute » (*étagère* est féminin) serait correct, mais pas idiomatique. On utilise cette construction pour désigner la position qui définit un objet. On peut dire de même « l'étagère du milieu » (s'il y en a trois), « la porte du fond », « le mur de gauche », etc.

Avec l'adjectif *haut*, « l'objet le plus haut » signifierait sauf précision contraire l'objet dont la dimension verticale est la plus élevée (*tallest object*) et non celui dont la position verticale est la plus élevée (*highest object*).

On ne dirait pas « la dernière étagère » parce qu'il n'y a pas d'ordre de parcours intrinsèque. On pourrait très bien parcourir les étagères de haut en bas, et alors la dernière étagère serait la plus basse, c'est-à-dire celle du bas. On dit par contre « le dernier étage » puisque les étages sont numérotés de bas en haut (le premier étage étant celui situé juste au dessus du rez-de-chaussée).

Comment: Merci. Plussoyé. Que signifie **précision contraire** dans votre 2e paragraphe ?

Comment: @LePressentiment “Sauf précision contraire” = par défaut, sauf si le contexte donne une indication qui va dans un autre sens.

Comment: Merci de me réjouir. Sa traduction en anglais = "Unless otherwise stated" ?

Answer (score 1):

Les deux formes sont valables, excepté le genre du mot étagère (féminin).

> Je n'arrive pas à atteindre l'étagère la plus haute.
>   
>   Je n'arrive pas à atteindre la dernière étagère.